# Select options not changing in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have a select box, on a certain event the potential select options change.

$('#select2').html(''); //to clear it's existing values
$('#select2').append('Option 3');
$('#select2').append('Option 4');

This code works fine in Firefox and Chrome. However, in Internet Explorer 8, the options don't change on the html pages. When I use alert($('#select2').html()); , it alerts the correct options (Option 3, Option 4), however on the actual select, the options are the original ones.  Has anyone encountered this.  Is there anyway to make the page display the new select options properly.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this.  Can you post a Snippet or a Fiddle of the problem?  Assuming `select2` is a select element, you should append an option child like this:  `$('#select2').append('<option>Option 4</option>');`

Comment: It is $('#select2').append('<option>Option 4</option>'), mine was just a typo in the question.  Also, I tried js fiddle but it does not seem to work in internet explorer 8

Comment: I only have IE11 available for testing at the moment.  If you post your fiddle, someone may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that changing the html of a select does not rerender the select correctly in internet explorer 8.  Instead, I changed the html of the div above the select which worked. Something like:

```
var parent = $('#select2').parent("div");
var newHTML = parent.html();
parent.html("");
parent.html(newHTML);
```